# Active one main menu at a time hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

please take a look at the image, here I am tried to do

1. If I click on **"Fan Panels"** The other two menus will be visible. Which is currently working fine. and here three menus will be visible.
2. If I click on **"Entertain Art"** menu the **"Score Art"** and **"Fan Panels"** need to be hidden, but the "Entertain Art" still need to show.
3. If I click on **"Score Art"** the **"Fan Panels"** and **"Entertain Art"** menu need to hidden, but the **"Score Art"** still need to show.

If you think about the code here it is :

```
{{#each categories}}
  <li class="nav-list__item">
    <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="{{url}}" title="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
  </li>
{/each}}
```

The website is under preview mode

Tts Big-commerce so menu displaying frontend with the dynamic syntax I think we can do it with javascript and jquery to find text and hide them what you suggest?

FOR EXAMPLE CODE:

```html
    <ul id="primeNav" class="nav-list nav-list--prime">
        <li class="nav-list__item">
            <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="#" title="Fan Panels">Fan Panels</a>
        <li class="nav-list__item">
            <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="#" title="Entertain Art">Entertain Art</a>
        <li class="nav-list__item">
            <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="#" title="Score Art">Score Art</a>
    </ul>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Add/Remove classes dynamically based on the click using JS and apply the styles using css.

Comment: you can use $('.div_class').removeClass('hidden'); and $('.div_class').addClass('hidden');

Comment: @NeenuLinoy there are only one class going to use on all menus

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai div are not different sir

Comment: you should give different class name for each div, and in onclick event you have to apply hidden class to the div that you want to hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code alternatively -

Edit 3 -
Here's the newly updated code

```js
/* Conditional Page Options */
var url = window.location.href;
var url = url.replace(/\//g, '');

var sub_url = location.protocol + location.host;
var page = url.replace(sub_url, '');


/* conditional click actions */
if (page == "entertain-art") {
  $("#primeNav .nav-list__item").hide();
  $("#primeNav .nav-list__item:nth-child(2)").show(); // revised
} else if (page == "score-art") {
  $("#primeNav .nav-list__item").hide();
  $("#primeNav .nav-list__item:nth-child(3)").show(); // revised
} else {
  $("#primeNav .nav-list__item-link").on('click', function() {
    var index = $(".nav-list__item-link").index(this);

    if (index == 0) {
      $("#primeNav .nav-list__item").show();
    } else {
      $("#primeNav .nav-list__item").hide();
      $(this).parent().show();
    }
  });
}
$("#primeNav .nav-list__item:nth-child(4)").show(); // revised
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="primeNav" class="nav-list nav-list--prime">
  <li class="nav-list__item">
    <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="#" title="Fan Panels">Fan Panels</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-list__item">
    <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="#" title="Entertain Art">Entertain Art</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-list__item">
    <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="#" title="Score Art">Score Art</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi Gru I have updated the question please take it you can create your own HTML.

Comment: It's not an answer!

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj I hope this will help you.

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj I just removed initial hidden condition. You can try it now.

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj check revised answer. i hope this will help.

Comment: @Thanks for your efforts its work but its hide all menu when i click on entrain or score menu

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj that `.eq()` not working properly, plz revised newly updated code lines.

Answer (score 0):

try it.

**UPDATE* : without adding new class name

```js
//Without any new class name
$("#primeNav li").click(function(){
if($(this).text().trim()!="Fan Panels") //For Point 1, if click on FanPanel then show all
  {      
  
    $("#primeNav li").hide();  // hide all item 
    $(this).show();     // Show item which is clicked
  } 
})

//Added **menu** as classname to all anchor tag, also added another unique class name to handle individual.

//Older try
$(".menu2").click(function(){

console.log($(this).text());
if($(this).hasClass("menuFan")==false) //For Point 1, if click on FanPanel then show all
{
    $(".menu").hide();  // hide all item 
    $(this).show();     // Show item which is clicked
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primeNav" class="nav-list nav-list--prime">
                            <li class="nav-list__item">
                            <a class="nav-list__item-link menu menuFan" href="#" title="Fan Panels">Fan Panels</a>
                            <li class="nav-list__item">
                            <a class="nav-list__item-link menu menuEnt" href="#" title="Entertain Art">Entertain Art</a>
                            <li class="nav-list__item">
                            <a class="nav-list__item-link menu menuScore" href="#" title="Score Art">Score Art</a>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: you are almost right just I have only one anchor tag <a class="nav-list__item-link" href="{{url}}" title="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>  so i can only add one class how to add three classes for different menu? all three comes with one anchor tag

Comment: then you can compare the text of clicked anchor tag, and do the things.

Comment: Your code works but its showing again when full page showing again.